# What is $S^3/S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, quotient-spaces, spheres

I have been given this space in a question but I am unsure what it means

I know that $S^3=\{(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C^2}\mid |z_{1}|^2 + |z_{2}|^2=1 \}$

Could you help me understand what set of points are contained in $S^3/S^1$ and perhaps what it is homeomorphic to?

---

Motivation:
[image: motivation]

Comment: @PeterFranek according to that question $S^n / S^k \sim S^n \vee S^{k+1}$. This would imply the space is homeomorphic to the standard sphere $S^2$

Comment: @PeterFranek this is what I am trying to work towards - please see my updated question

Comment: The quotient is the _complex projective line_ (a.k.a. the _Riemann sphere_), and the quotient map is the _Hopf map_. Both are explained in great detail elsewhere on this site. I hope having the proper search terms is helpful. :)

Comment: [Source of this question.](http://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/teaching/Exam/papers/2015/MATH3281_WE01_TopologyIII.pdf)